# MySQL Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string: '' with '\' infront of unicode character

Tags: mysql, utf-8, bulkinsert

I have a bunch of csv-files and I came across a case where strangely enough '\' utf8 are in front of unicode characters e.g.

```
Tom;\Éscobar;123
```

and when doing a bulk insert via:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv'
INTO TABLE TEST_TABLE
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

the error: Invalid utf8 character string: '' is thrown.
I wonder if this is a bug in MySQL LOAD DATA or if I am missing something here.

```
MySQL-Version 5.7.16
```

Comment: It sounds like the file was improperly encoded.  Can you get the hex for that line?

Comment: The original line was: \朱坤 in hex its 5c67315764. I can reproduce it with any combination \+[some unicode char]. The file is encoded in utf8

Comment: Hmmm... No `CHARACTER SET` treats `5c67315764` as `\朱坤`.

Comment: The utf8 hex for `朱坤` is `E69CB1 E59DA4` (without the space)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The hex dump is `5c e69cb1 e59da4`. I don't see anything unusual. Do you?

Comment: That is the correct utf8 (or utf8mb4) for the string.  Dig back further -- what process generated the file?

Comment: The string was generated by an extract from another database and exported as .csv (unfortunately I can't influence that). However, since I can also write such a file I now think this is a MySQL LOAD FROM FILE bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out what the pattern is, ...

1. load the CSV into `VARBINARY` or `BLOB` column(s).
2. run a SQL, probably using the `REPLACE()` function`, to cleanse the data (remove the blackslashes).
3. do a suitable `ALTER`, probably `MODIFY COLUMN ... VARCHAR(...) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` to get it into a text format.